# How to put a subscript or superscript in a grid Extra table?

Tags: r, subscript, gridextra

I would like to put a subscript on "1" of (PM1) in the first row name of my grid extra table, but i don't succeed.

I tried also with expression function, it doesn't work.

Thank you for helping

J.

Here is my code :

```
myData <- matrix((1:15),  nrow=5, ncol=3,) 
colnames(myData) <- c("Group A", "Group B", "Group C") 
rownames(myData) <- c("**PM<sub>1**", "b", "c", "d", "e")
print(myData)
Tmin <- ttheme_minimal()
grid.arrange(  tableGrob(myData, theme=Tmin))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(gridExtra)
myData <- matrix((1:15),  nrow=5, ncol=3,) 
colnames(myData) <- c("Group A", "Group B", "Group C") 
rownames(myData) <- c("**PM<sub>1**", "b", "c", "d", "e")
print(myData)
#>              Group A Group B Group C
#> **PM<sub>1**       1       6      11
#> b                  2       7      12
#> c                  3       8      13
#> d                  4       9      14
#> e                  5      10      15
Tmin <- ttheme_minimal()
grid.arrange(  tableGrob(myData, rows = c(~PM[1], ~b,~c,~d,~e), theme=Tmin))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Is it possible btw to add a footnote with this package? I managed to do it with gt package but it is quite complicated for me, so I prefer work on grid.arrange. Thank you for your answer